# Legal Combo in Modern?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-modern

I came across a great milling combo, however before I invest in the deck, I wanted to make sure it's legal. A rep at my LGS thinks not, but I wanted a 2nd (and more) opinion.

Turn #1: Land + 1 generic 1 drop flyer.
Turn #2: Land + [Mindcrank](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=233078)
Turn #3: Land + [Duskmantle Guildmage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=366328)
Turn #4: Land + Protection/Removal. Activate the DG's 1st ability via attack, Tome Scour, Thought Scour, etc. 
This will create an infinite milling loop and win by turn 4 if everything goes right. If opp has artifact removal, I can thrown in a Padeem or Orbs of Warding. Then even if opp has creature removal or board wipe, I'll have 4x each.

To simplify this inquiry, I have precisely, squarely, meticulously narrowed the specific questions that are the basis on my query...

1 - Will this combo work? 
2 - Have you personally tried it and to what extent of success did you achieve? 
3 - What modifications would you suggest?

Thank you.

Comment: I assume by "legal" you mean "does this have the effects I think it does?" Also, the question might be clearer if you pared it down to just ask about Mindcrank and Duskmantle Guildmage plus a way to kick it off; while decks do generally need more than the core combo to actually win games, that's not part of the rules question.

Comment: It would also help if you explain why the LGS rep thought was illegal about it. Is it a question about if the specific cards involved are legal in Modern? Or is it about if the specific cards have the effect you think?

Comment: "Legal combo in Modern?" makes no sense. Are you asking if this works according to the rules of MTG, or are you asking if those cards are available in the Modern format?

Comment: If you are wondering if the combo contains any Banned or Restricted Cards, you can check the current modern banlist here: [MTG Banlist](http://magic.wizards.com/en/game-info/gameplay/rules-and-formats/banned-restricted) or on each card's gatherer page under legality. Both cards are modern legal.

Comment: Wow. Well, exactly specifically absolutely I intended to precisely ask if, beyond reasonable doubt, to a full extent, if the combo would work. I already checked that the cards are not banned, but thanks anyway. Hopefully this clears things up to a point, matter of fact, and to a full extent.